# How to Implement load balancer in my Azure Function App?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have created Azure function which takes the http request and returns the json file into the blob. I am wondering how to implement load balancer in my azure function in case In my application if there are too many request it shouldn't fail or take too much time since I am dealing with 5-10gb data.

Sample code:

```
app = func.FunctionApp()
@app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger1")
@app.route(route="hello", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def test_function(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
            status_code=200
        )
```

Comment: Do you use the consumption plan? Is the [autoscaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#scale) not suffient for your use case?

Comment: @PeterBons I am using Consumption Plan. Do I need to switch to other plan for much better Autoscaling?

Comment: Only if you think you will hit the limits using the consumption plan but I doubt you will hit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @*PeterBons* for the comment.

As @*PeterBons* mentioned, you can use inbuilt scaling feature of Azure functions.

- By default, Azure Functions monitors the load of your application and creates the host instances automatically as needed.
- This scaling feature is useful to handle the load of requests.
- If you are using Consumption plan for your function app, instances of the Functions host will be added dynamically and removed based on the number requests received.

In case of Premium or App Service Plan, you can scale up resources according to the requirement.

[image]

[image]

***References:***

[Overview of Hosting Plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#overview-of-plans)

Comment: When you say "premium" you mean dedicated or elastic premium?